# Kafka producer using multiple threads in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I have a Ktor application that send events using RSocket.

These events need to also be sent to Kafka now, so I created the following code:

```
    suspend fun publishEvents(flow: SharedFlow<Pair<String, String>>) {
        val producer = KafkaProducer<String, String>(mapOf())
        flow.collect { 
            producer.send(ProducerRecord("topic", it.first, it.second))
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the producer is not being able to keep up with more than 5k events per second, 250 bytes each, one partition, default settings. Increasing the number of partitions did not help, nor did tweaking properties like compression, linger, batch size and acks. It seems I reached some kind of hard limit.

Modifying the code like this:

```
suspend fun publishEvents(flow: SharedFlow<Pair<String, String>>) {
        val producer = KafkaProducer<String, String>(mapOf())
        val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads)
        flow.collect { 
            executorService.submit {
                producer.send(ProducerRecord("topic", it.first, it.second))
            }
        }
    }
```

Fixed the issue, with two threads almost 10k per second was sent, but I am concerned about losing ordering guarantees for the same key, because of the multiple threads. How can I change this to avoid this issue? And is there a producer setting to change the number of threads?

EDIT:

Turns out this solution does not work anyway, it introduces a memory leak. And the bottleneck does not seem to be in the producer, since tweaking the configuration makes no difference and no exception is thrown. This is probably related to coroutines / shared flow. How can I fix the memory leak? Multiple threads was the only thing able to improve throughput.

Comment: You shouldn't create more than one producer in the same app (or one per method call). The producer is thread-safe, so should be reused.

Comment: There is only one instance being used inside the flow collect method. The publishEvents method is called only once.

Comment: You should create the producer when the server starts rather than when calling any method. The below answer addresses ordering. Reduce retries and max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1. Send method calls are FIFO. Regarding using flows, you might want to use ReactiveX or Vertx Kafka libraries to get client side backpressure guarantees, and you don't really need an executor service

Answer (score 1):

The Java `KafkaProducer` `send` method is already sending the `ProducerRecord` in an async way. It does so by keeping a buffer, or batch, and only sending the `batch.size` every `linger.ms`.

So to increase throughput of the `KafkaProducer` you can increase this `batch.size` to allow sending *more* records at once. When doing so you also need to increase the `linger.ms` property which defaults to `0`.

If `linger.ms` is set to `0` some batching will still occur, but very suboptimal.

Alongside these two configuration properties you might also want to consider increasing `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to allow more than the default `5` connections at the same time.

Comment: Tweaking the configuration did not help. I edited the question with more details.